# datagridview и зависимые combobox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Допустим, имеется `datagridview`, где есть 2 колонки с типом `datagridviewcombobox`(далее `cb`).

Нужно сделать, что бы от выбора значения в первом `cb` зависели значения во втором `cb`.

Проблема в том, что когда я создам вторую строчку и выберу в первом `cb` другое значение, то во втором `cb` первой строки сбросится значение `cb` так как `cb` действует на весь `datagridviewcombobox`.

Можно ли этого избежать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создавайте и загружайте каждый комбобокс отдельно.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;

    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
    row = GetComboBox();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

    dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;
}

void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1] = GetCell(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
}

private DataGridViewRow GetComboBox()
{
    DataGridViewRow rowDG = new DataGridViewRow();
    rowDG.CreateCells(dataGridView1);

    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell_CB1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

    cell_CB1.Items.AddRange("Значение ComboBox'a 1");
    cell_CB1.Items.AddRange("Значение ComboBox'a 2");
    cell_CB1.Items.AddRange("Значение ComboBox'a 3");

    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell_CB2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

    rowDG.Cells[0] = cell_CB1;
    rowDG.Cells[1] = cell_CB2;

    return rowDG;
}

private DataGridViewComboBoxCell GetCell(string value)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell_CB2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

    switch(value)
    {
        case "Значение ComboBox'a 1":
            cell_CB2.Items.AddRange("Значение ComboBox'a 101");
            cell_CB2.Items.AddRange("Значение ComboBox'a 102");
            cell_CB2.Items.AddRange("Значение ComboBox'a 103");
            break;

        case "Значение ComboBox'a 2":
            cell_CB2.Items.AddRange("Значение ComboBox'a 201");
            cell_CB2.Items.AddRange("Значение ComboBox'a 202");
            cell_CB2.Items.AddRange("Значение ComboBox'a 203");
            break;

        default:
            cell_CB2.Items.AddRange("Значение ComboBox'a 301");
            cell_CB2.Items.AddRange("Значение ComboBox'a 302");
            cell_CB2.Items.AddRange("Значение ComboBox'a 303");
            break;

    }           
    return cell_CB2;
}
```

Comment: Соответственно, если юзер создает новые строки, то я на каждое событие добавление строки, должен повесить обработчик создания ComboBox'ов?

Comment: Обновил код, и да, в событии создания новой строки добавлять свои комбобоксы.

Comment: а можно пример, который иллюстрирует следующий сценарий: К DataGridView подключается List<> с двумя полями и на каждое поле генерируется свой ComboBox с рандомными значениями?

Comment: @iluxa1810, можно. Но мне кажется будет правильным задать новый вопрос.